# What's the size of carbon dioxide?

Tags: molecules

My question is very simple. How big is a [carbon dioxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) ($\mathrm{CO}_2$) molecule, i.e. the width, length and height of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$CO_2$ molecule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_data#Structure_and_properties)

[image]

The molecule is linear (all three atoms are in a co-linear line). The C=O bond is 116 pm, so the entire molecule (from centre of O to other O) is 232 pm. The extent in the other directions normal to the axis of symmetry is not well-defined as the electron cloud is diffuse and depends significantly on environment.

Comment: alright, i've got to admit, that i'm not an scientist... so i've you take a millimeter, how far beyond the dot (0.000.....) must i go before i see these numbers (232 pm)... Thanks :P

Comment: picometer is $10^{-12} m$ i.e. a decimal followed by 11 zeros.

Comment: alright, so it is around the 0,000 000 000 232 meter... thanks for your help.