# Why does wavelength decide the size/diameter of these holes in the microwave door?

Tags: radiation, wavelength, microwaves

I've read [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29357/how-does-the-grid-on-the-microwave-oven-window-prevent-microwave-radiation-from) that microwaves are blocked by the holes in a microwave window because the holes on the door are small enough to prevent the microwaves from passing through. However, if wavelength is only the distance between successive crests of a wave, why should that decide what a certain wave can fit through? Why is amplitude not the deciding factor and is there a way to explain this visually?

Comment: It has to do with boundary conditions (you can use simple optics and things like the single- and double-slit concepts) and interference, which only "allow" certain wavelengths to pass through.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If photons move linearly, what's actually stopping them from passing through a microwave oven mesh?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55262/if-photons-move-linearly-whats-actually-stopping-them-from-passing-through-a-m)

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149607/what-is-the-relationship-between-faraday-cage-mesh-size-and-attenuation-of-cell